# Set size text in mdframed

Tags: tikz-styles, mdframed, text

I wish to know if it's possibile to set the size of the text inside a mdframed. The next step is, if possible to set the text in italics form. I have the following code

```
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\newenvironment{CodeCheckFrame}[1][]{%
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        frametitle={#1},
        skipabove=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        skipbelow=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        linewidth=0.5pt,
        frametitlerule=true,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!30
    ]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the font size with `font=...`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\newenvironment{CodeCheckFrame}[1][]{%
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        frametitle={\normalsize#1},
        skipabove=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        skipbelow=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        linewidth=0.5pt,
        frametitlerule=true,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!30,
        font=\tiny
    ]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{CodeCheckFrame}[All my little ducklings]
are swimming in the lake
\end{CodeCheckFrame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks marmot. Could I ask to you if there is a way to set the style in Italics? Thanks in advance

Comment: @GianniSpear Sure. Just use `font=\tiny\itshape` or something like that.

Comment: thanks. I spent hours to find a solution. Thanks!